# Prove an inequality

Tags: calculus

I want to show that following:
$$\left(\frac{n^2-1}{n^2}\right)^n\sqrt{\frac{n+1}{n-1}}\leq 1; ~~n\geq 2$$ and $n$ is an integer.

After some simplifications, I got left hand-side as
$$LHS:\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n-\frac{1}{2}} \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n+\frac{1}{2}}$$
It is clear that the 1st term is less than 1, but I do not have any clue how I can show that multiplication is less than 1.

Can someone give me some hints?

Comment: i'm a little bit out of this buisness, but somehow this reminds me at bernoullis inequality...

Answer (score 0):

Let

$$f(x) = \Big(\frac{x^2-1}{x^2}\Big)^x\sqrt{\frac{x+1}{x-1}}$$

Show that $f$ is monotonically increasing for $x\geq 2$ and that $f\rightarrow 1$ as $x\rightarrow\infty$.

**Edit:** Might be easier to show that $\log f$ is monotonically increasing and approaches zero.

Comment: Doing what you suggest with $\log(f)$, we can find a nice asymptotic $f=1-\frac{1}{6 x^3}-\frac{2}{15 x^5}+O\left(\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)^6\right)$

Answer (score 0):

Consider on $(-1,1)$ the function (with motivation $x=\frac1n$)
$$
f(x)=\ln\bigl(1-x^2\bigr)+\frac x2\bigl(\ln(1+x)-\ln(1-x)\bigr)-\frac16\ln\bigl(1-x^4\bigr)
$$
Then
$$
f'(x)=-\frac{x}{1-x^2}+\frac12\bigl(\ln(1+x)-\ln(1-x)\bigr)+\frac16\frac{4x^3}{1-x^4}
$$
where we see that $f(0)=0=f'(0)$. The next derivative is
\begin{align}
f''(x)&=-\frac{2x^2}{(1-x^2)^2}+\frac{2x^2}{1-x^4}+\frac83\frac{x^6}{(1-x^4)^2}\\
&=-\frac{4x^4}{(1-x^4)(1-x^2)}+\frac83\frac{x^6}{(1-x^4)^2}\\
&=-\frac43·\frac{3x^4+x^6}{(1-x^4)^2}
\end{align}
which is always negative for $x\ne 0$. Then for $x>0$ the linear Taylor polynomial with quadratic remainder term gives
$$
f(x)=\frac12f''(\theta x)x^2<0
$$
and taking the exponential of $f(x)<0$ gives
$$
\bigl(1-x^2\bigr)·\left(\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right)^{\frac x2}<\bigl(1-x^4\bigr)^{\frac16}.
$$
Replacing $x=\frac1n$ and taking the $n$th power of the inequality results in the requested inequality,
$$
\left(1-\frac1{n^2}\right)^n·\sqrt{\frac{n+1}{n-1}}<\left(1-\frac1{n^4}\right)^{\frac n6}<1.
$$