# Any elementary proof of the monotonicity of $a_{n} =(1+\frac{1}{n})^{n+\frac{1}{2}}$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

We do have the elementary proof of the monotonicity of $(1+\frac{1}{n})^{n}$ and $(1+\frac{1}{n})^{n+1}$ .

Here is an example.

First we have
$$\ln \left(1+\frac{1}{n+1}\right) = \int_{1}^{1+\frac{1}{n+1}}\frac{1}{x}\,dx>\frac{1}{n+2}=\frac{n\left(n+1\right)}{n+2}\int_{1+\frac{1}{n+1}}^{1+\frac{1}{n}}\,dx > n\int_{1+\frac{1}{n+1}}^{1+\frac{1}{n}}\frac{1}{x}\,dx$$
Now add
$$n\ln \left(1+\frac{1}{n+1}\right) = n\int_{1}^{1+\frac{1}{n+1}}\frac{1}{x}\,dx$$
We get
$$\left(n+1\right)\ln \left(1+\frac{1}{n+1}\right) > n\int_{1}^{1+\frac{1}{n}}\frac{1}{x}\,dx = n\ln \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)$$

So can we solve the monotonicity of $a_{n} =(1+\frac{1}{n})^{n+\frac{1}{2}}$ similiarly? Or by any other elegant elementary proof?

Comment: What about https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1620035/42969 ?

Comment: But I want to get some new elementary proofs like the one in my post

Comment: If $b_n$ and $c_n$ are increasing positive sequences then $b_n c_n$ is also increasing. You have $a_n = (1+\frac{1}{n})^{n+1} (1+\frac{1}{n})^{\frac{-1}{2}}$, a product of positive increasing sequences.

Comment: @Paul But I think one of them is decreasing

Comment: Saw that - changed it a bit!

Comment: I thought $(1+\frac{1}{n})^{n+1}$  is decreasing.

Comment: Sorry yes, writing as a product creates increasing/decreasing issue. Scrub that approach.

Comment: @Calum Gilhooley Is that not the same problem? $b_n$ is increasing while $c_n$ is decreasing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$$ \left(n+\tfrac{1}{2}\right)\log\left(1+\tfrac{1}{n}\right)=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{n+\tfrac{1}{2}}{x+n}\,dx= \int_{-1/2}^{1/2}\frac{1}{1+\frac{2x}{2n+1}}\,dx = \int_{0}^{1/2}\frac{2}{1-\left(\frac{2x}{2n+1}\right)^2}\,dx $$
produces

> $$ \left(n+\tfrac{1}{2}\right)\log\left(1+\tfrac{1}{n}\right)= \int_{0}^{1}\frac{dx}{1-\left(\frac{x}{2n+1}\right)^2} $$

hence it is clear that the RHS is decreasing, since for any $x\in(0,1)$ and any $N>n$ we have
$$ \frac{1}{1-\left(\frac{x}{2N+1}\right)^2} < \frac{1}{1-\left(\frac{x}{2n+1}\right)^2}.$$

Answer (score 0):

The second derivative of $\log a_n$ is positive,
so the first derivative is increasing, with limit 0,
so the first derivative is negative,
so the sequence is monotonic decreasing.

Comment: Yeah thank you, but can you help me judge whether I can generalize the method in the post to this problem?