# $\big(1+\frac{1}{n}\big)^{n+\frac{1}{2}}$ is a decreasing sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, inequality, monotone-functions

I've got to study the monotonicity of a few Euler like sequences, for example $\big(1+\frac{1}{n}\big)^{n+1}$ or $\big(1-\frac{1}{n}\big)^{n}$. Those are relatively easy to solve using either AM-GM or Bernoulli's inequality, but some of them can be solved using properties of $\big(1+\frac{1}{n}\big)^{n}$ indirectly, such as $\frac{\sqrt[n]{n!}}{n}$ (in this case via induction).

This particular exercise first requires to prove the extension of Bernoulli's inequality $$(1+x)^n>1+nx+\frac{n(n-1)}{2}x^2~\forall~n>3,~x>0$$ which is obvious from the binomial theorem.

Then, it asks to study the monotonicity of the sequence $$x_n=\bigg(1+\frac{1}{n}\bigg)^{n+\frac{1}{2}},~n>3$$

Trying to prove that $x_{n-1}>x_n$, we arrive at the following inequality: $$\bigg(1+\frac{1}{n^2-1}\bigg)^{2n}>1+\frac{2}{n-1}$$
which I'm having a hard time to prove using the first part of the exercise.

I've also tried other methods, but I can't seem to figure it out. Please, I need a little help.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3259175/42969 or https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2979085/42969 – both found [with Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Cbigg(1%2B%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7Bn%7D%5Cbigg)%5E%7Bn%2B%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B2%7D%7D%24%2C%20AND%20content%3Adecreasing)

Comment: Jeez, how did I miss that... I had actually tried adding one more term but I think I missed something afterwards. Thanks @MartinR